# Decouple data from code

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, decoupling

Let's say I have a table called Couriers in my database and an Entity Framework class also called Couriers (DbContext.Couriers), with this example data:
Id: 1. Name: UPS
Id: 2. Name: DHL

I have extended this class with two subclasess CourierUPS and CourierDHL, and both two have a new method called PrintSticker(), which is different in UPS and DHL (each company needs a different sticker format).

I also have a view with a combo to select between UPS or DHL and a button that calls the PrintSticker method of  the selected Courier.

Well, the problem is that I can create the object with an IF statement (if selectedCourier = "UPS" create new CourierUPS elseif selectedCourier = "DLH" create new CourierDHL... it's just pseudo code), but it is not a good way, because if I want to create FedEx courier in the future, I will need to change that IF statement, so I think I will become a mess.

What I want to achieve is a way to dinamycally obtain this:

C#

`CourierUPS courier = new CourierUPS;`

VB.NET

`Dim courier as CourierUPS = new CourierUPS`

The questions are:

1) Is there a simple way to save the name of the class in the table (CourierUPS, CourierDHL, etc.), and use it the code to create the new objects?

2) Is there a simple way to dynamically construct the name of the class, attaching the name of the courier (DHL or UPS) to the "Courier" word? Courier + UPS = CourierUPS, so our code will use that class.

Both C# or VB.NET solutions would be appreciatted.

Thank you

Comment: Abstract factrory pattern seems like a good choice to me.

Comment: You could look at `Activator.CreateInstance()` as another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And option that you can try is to create a factory dictionary for creating each type.

Start out with this:

```
var factory = new Dictionary<string, Func<Courier>>()
{
    { "UPS", () => new CourierUPS() },
    { "DHL", () => new CourierDHL() },
};
```

Now you can create either the "UPS" or "DHL" courier like this:

```
var courier = factory["UPS"].Invoke();
```

But, if you now want to configure a new courier you can pass your dictionary into a method that can add in "FedEx", and you can add it like so:

```
factory["FedEx"] = () => new CourierFedEx();
```

Now you can do this back in your main code:

```
var courier = factory["FedEx"].Invoke();
```

It's basic, but it works.